# Retrieve data from List of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am declaring an list of arrays of integers.

```
  List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I populate it:

```
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (int j=1; j<10; j++){ 
      int[] currentadding = {i,j};
      list.add(currentadding);
    }
  }
```

How do I read the values stored?

Comment: Have you checked the `ArrayList` java api?

Comment: @ Kugathasan Abimaran Yes, but I am learning and I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over the list using the *advanced for-loop* and use the `int[]` you get from the list on every iteration.

```
for(int[] arr : list) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // System.out.println(arr[0]);
}
```

Or you can use the *standard for-loop* as well.

```
for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int[] arr = list.get(i);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // System.out.println(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: To see individual values stored is this the best way?      for (int k=0; k<list.size(); k++){
         String a = Integer.toString(list.get(k)[0]);
         String b = Integer.toString(list.get(k)[1]);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a + "-" + b);
     }

Comment: @geo - Not the best way IMHO, but certainly a valid/correct way and probably depending on your needs, the best way for your case. Also, why not try to use the advanced `for` loop I mentioned?

Comment: @ R.J I prefer not to use the advanced for loop because I need the "i" value to do some things not mentioned in my example.

Comment: @geo - Whichever serves your needs the best, should be used. I just suggested it. Probably someone else who might land up here could use it if they don't have the same constraints as you! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can `foreach`:

```
for(int[] currentadding : list) {
// access mutate currentadding
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over array lists with a for loop like

```
for(int[] x : list){
 // do something to x
}
```

or if you know the index of what your looking for you can use

```
list.get(*index*);
```